# ANTLR: loop did not match anything at character '%'

Tags: java, regex, parsing, antlr, lexer

My ANTLR grammar looks like this.

```
grammar ProgCalc;

options {
  language = Java;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
  output=AST;
  backtrack=true;
}

/* Parser rules */
eval
  : exp=add;

add
  : term ( PLUS^ term | MINUS^ term ) *;

term
  : factor ( MULT^ factor | MOD^ factor )*;

factor
  : number 
  | VARIABLE
  | '('! add^ ')'!
  ;

number
  : DEC | HEX | OCT;

/* Lexer Rules*/
VARIABLE: ('a'..'z' |'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9'|'_')* ;
DEC     : ('1'..'9')('0'..'9')+;
HEX     : '0x' ('0'..'9' | 'a'..'f' | 'A'..'F')+;
OCT     : '0' ('0'..'7')*;

PLUS    : '+';
MINUS   : '-';
MULT    : '*';
MOD     : '%';

WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+ { $channel = HIDDEN; };
```

When I compile, it was successful.
But as I parsed with an expression(eg. 5%3*5), I get an error.

> ```
> line 1:1 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character '%'
> line 1:3 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character '*'
> line 1:5 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character '<EOF>'
> line 1:5 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
> ```

Could anyone please check my grammar and correct it?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DEC` lexer rule requires at least 2 digits due to the `+` operator. I believe you meant to write:

```
DEC : ('1'..'9') ('0'..'9')*;
```